# tu vs você in the imperative in common spoken portuguese

Tags: uso-de-palavras, formalismo

Is the rule for when to prefer tu vs você different with the imperative? I actually thought that it was.

I thought phrases like "vai fora" were typical, and so you would in casual conversation use the "tu" form for imperatives. Today I covered phrases with *ver* and *virar* that both used the você form, and were equally (perhaps more so) general phrases.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean in your last sentence. Do you mean you were taught in class to command «veja bem» and «vire à direita» if you address someone by *você*, rather than say «vê bem» and «vira à direita»?

Comment: Yes, I remember, it was vire .. later looking in the conjugation tables, I noticed that that was not the form I was expecting.

Comment: I'm just thinking that when people say things like, «vai fora», they're not consciously substituting the second person imperative for the third person; they're probablly substituting the third person indicative for the imperative. It's just that third person indicative and second person (affirmative) imperative are alike in nearly all verbs (the verb *ser* is the only exception I can think of).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar rules are simple. If you address someone by *você* then the imperative, as everything else, goes third person singular; if you address someone by *tu*, then, well, it’s second person singular:

> Como está (você)? Sente-se aqui. Esteja à vontade. Tome um café, coma um bolinho.
>
> Come estás (tu)? Senta-te aqui. Está à vontade. Toma um café, come um bolinho.

And in European Portuguese that’s that: *tu* is informal whereas *você* is semi-formal (*o senhor, a senhora* is formal), so you’re very conscious that *tome um café, coma um bolinho* implies some formality, and *toma um café, come um bolinho* implies familiarity; so with any particular person you either use one all the time or the other all the time, and never mix the two.

In most of Brazil *tu*, if used at all, and *você* are both informal, and so it is easier to mix the two. And it is common in colloquial language to use *você* together with the second person singular imperative:

> Como está (você)? Toma um café, come um bolinho. Oi, você aí! Vai fora!

Now this is colloquial language, so you won't find it in conjugation tables, and you have website after website telling you that in examinations, job interviews, and other formal settings, you are required to follow proper grammar. [Here’s one](http://vestibular.uol.com.br/resumo-das-disciplinas/portugues/modo-imperativo-e-uniformidade-de-tratamento.htm), and [here’s another](http://sualingua.com.br/2009/05/14/tu-x-voce/) bearing on the use of the imperativo. On the other hand I would have thought Brazilians will not think you have a spoon up your nose just because you follow grammar rules for imperative use. But I am Portuguese and you may want Brazilian advice on this point.

Comment: I think the question was more in the line of "in the context of Brazilian mixing of tu and você, is there a preference in the use of the 2nd persons imperative form for some verbs?" That will be hard to answer, because some verbs are also more formal than others and therefore will tend for that reason alone to be used more frequently with the 3rd person forms. Another reason is that the imperative forms are shared with other tenses. This makes simple counting impossible; you have to rely on good corpus annotations and control for register.

Comment: @Artefacto My reading is different: I hear people speaking like this, and grammars tell me a different thing.